# Amount to choice necessary to prove instances of Tychonoff theorem

Tags: general-topology, axiom-of-choice

Let $I$ be a fixed nonempty set. I would like to know how much choice is necessary in order to prove that the product of **any** $I$-indexed family of compact topological spaces is compact (under the product topology). The usual proof of Alexander subbase theorem gives no information about that, because it is based on Zorn's lemma.

Comment: The Tychonoff theorem is equivalent to the axiom of choice, thus no weaker statement will imply it.

Comment: If you retrace the proof of the axiom of choice *from* Tychonoff's theorem you will see that assuming this holds every family of size $I$ implies the axiom of choice for families of size $I$. Therefore we have a lower-bound on the strength of this assertion.

Comment: @Christoph: The **full** Tychonoff theorem. This is a restriction of the theorem.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh I see, the question is "how much choice" we need for fixed $I$.